# cfs collection showing error in react.component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-component, cfs

I have cfs collection for file uploading. I have already used this in the template and its working well. Now I have to use this react.component but its showing this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: fsFile is not defined`. I have added FS.Collection but its still showing error. Its working in when I using the template but not working in the react component. How can I solve this?

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import React from 'react';
import Switch from 'react-switch';
import {Events} from './../../api/events';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import moment from "moment";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default class AddEvent extends React.Component{
    EventForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let eventTitle = e.target.title.value;
        let file = $('#projectImage').get(0).files[0];


         if(file){
            fsFile = new FS.File(file);
            ProjectImages.insert(fsFile, function(err, result){
                if(!err){
                    var projectImage = '/cfs/files/ProjectImages/' + result._id;

                    // Insert Project
                    Events.insert({
                        name: eventTitle,
                        projectImage: projectImage
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Insert Project
            Events.insert({
                name: eventTitle
            });
        }

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="tab-pane fade" id="upEvents">
                <form className="upload-event-from" onSubmit={this.EventForm.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="event_title" placeholder="Event Title" name="title" />
                        <span className="error-message eventTitle"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group fg-icon">
                        <label>Upload Image</label>
                        <input type="file" className="form-control" name="projectImage" id="projectImage" />
                        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image"  />
                    </div>

                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn app-btn">Publish</button>
                    </center>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing FS defined anywhere. Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in that `fsFile = new FS.File(file);` line, you didn't declare the `let` but below of this line you called this again, I hope the issue happening from there, use like below

```
let fsFile = new FS.File(file);
ProjectImages.insert(fsFile, function(err, result){
    ....
```